# Using custom ports for SSL

Tags: ssl, iis-7

I am currently working on a strategy to migrate some of our websites/web applications to use HTTPS by default. All these applications use different host headers and are hosted on the same server. There are a number of ways of accomplishing this, but the most practical one seems to be to use a different port for every unique host header.

My question really is: **how common is to run a PUBLIC website on a custom port?** What are the chances that these requests will be blocked at a local firewall or corporate proxy level?

I used to see quite a few of these a decade ago, but they seem to have dwindled away since then, and I rarely see websites using custom ports now.

Comment: Voting to move to ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that nonstandard ports will be blocked at corporate firewalls and proxies. Instead of using various port numbers, perhaps investigate using multiple IP addresses (on the same machine, if you like), and offer your services on the standard port 443.

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is what I was afraid of. I have far too many domain names to get separate IP addresses for each of them. Do you have any links or stats which show that custom ports for HTTPS are a bad idea? I've been looking around but can't find anything to support or dispel this solution.

Comment: Maybe you can't find anything because nobody uses them. I can't think of *anywhere* on the public internet that uses a nonstandard port for HTTP or HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

(You would probably find better answers on ServerFault.)

Firewalls are typically used to restrict the usage of the Internet to a subset of ports and will therefore often be configured to as few ports as possible. This is not always the case and depends largely on the environment, but it's quite likely that ports other than a few usual ones (e.g. HTTP, HTTPS, POP3, IMAP, POP3S, IMAPS, SSH) will be blocked. It's typically a problem to deploy Java containers (e.g. Tomcat) on their default port (often 8443) for this reason (port 8443 is often used for development because you don't need to be root to use it on a Unix system).

The same applies to HTTP proxy servers. I don't have any stats, but you can look at the default configuration.

[For Squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringSquid):

```
acl SSL_ports port 443
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```

By default, it only allows `CONNECT` (which is what's used for HTTPS connections in a proxy) on port 443.

Similarly, [for TinyProxy](https://banu.com/cgit/tinyproxy/tree/etc/tinyproxy.conf.in?id=983d241db6b368106bfc7db1844105bb94ed54ad):

```
ConnectPort 443
ConnectPort 563
```

(and I wouldn't rely on port 563 generally speaking for an HTTPS server, it's for NNTPS anyway.)

Your other options are:

- Using a single certificate on this IP address with multiple Subject Alternative Name entries (one valid for each host name you need to serve).
- Using multiple IP addresses.
- Using [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), although that will not work with clients on IE on Windows XP (and with a few mobile clients, I think).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. As you pointed out, most proxies/firewalls come pretty tightly configured out of the box and ports need to be explicitly enabled.

SAN is an option but the issue is having to regenerate a new cert every time we add a new domain (which is several times a year).  Multiple IPs are increasingly harder to get hold of. And SNI is out of the question as we have to support XP based visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the web.config to make it the default way. I found an other [post about the port problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/284699/setup-iis-7-5-with-multiple-website-bindings-and-ssl).

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I have a good idea of how to make this work, but thanks for the additional info anyway. I'm more concerned about the practicality of using custom ports.